# Is battery consumption reduced if I close my laptop lid while it is connected to an external monitor?

Tags: display, battery, power

I've noticed that when I close my laptop screen while it is connected to an external monitor, battery lasts quite longer before I need to plug in my Lenovo laptop.

Is it just me or does closing the lid actually reduce battery consumption, since my laptop does not need to power the pixels on the screen? The monitor is plugged to the wall.

I think we refer to this as "calmshell mode"?

Comment: Is this a question about a Mac laptop? You reference your Lenovo laptop, with is a Windows device.

Comment: no it's not a Mac, I use windows. Does it make a difference thoguh?

Comment: It doesn't _really_ matter, but this is a site for Apple questions primarily.

Comment: ohh my bad I didn't know. I had no idea.

Comment: No problem. It's a generic question with an acceptable answer.

Comment: Question is not related to any Apple product or service

Answer (score 1):

Since your laptop display is off in clamshell mode, there would be some energy savings, making the battery last longer.